# Check ArrayList for duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

`Class:`

```
public class Variant
{
    private String variant;
    private String quantity;
    //getters and setters
}
```

`ArrayList:`

```
ArrayList<Variant> variantList = getVariantsList();
```

Now I want to check whether `variantList` contains a duplicate entry of `variant` or not? Please note that `variant` having two entries with different `quantity` are to be considered as duplicates.

Comment: @Downvoter reason for downvoting will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be due to the lack of description what you already tried. It's actually not that hard a problem.

Comment: Why is quantity String type and not int/long ??

Answer (score 3):

You can simply ovveride your equals method in your `Variant` class  and provide all the rules for equality in that method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      ..
```

Then you can use contains method or just pass it to a `Set`, that eliminates all your duplicates.

If you want `variant` having two entries with different quantity also considered as dup, then you can add that condition in your equals.

Comment: And if you use a `LinkedHashSet` you can still keep variant order. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check one object with other objects of list

Override equals method in Variant class

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null) {

            if (obj instanceof Variant) {
                Variant temp = (Variant) obj;
                return this.quantity.equals(temp.quantity); //for different quantity
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then check :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < variantList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < variantList.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    if (iList.get(i).equals(iList.get(j))) {
                        //logic when duplicate
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nope, won't work since `v` will always be contained by `variantList`, even if there is only one. Besides that you'd still have to override `equals()` which then should be part of the answer.

Comment: @developerbhuwan Apart from comment by @Thomas, Please note that `variant` having two entries with different `quantity` are to be considered as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals(Object obj)` method and try to compare the object on variant and quantity.

Try to loop thru the variantList and do check for duplicity using `variantList.contains(variant)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do:

- Override the `equals()` in your Variant class(minimal code below):
  Please note that the below code only checks for quantity and not the variant prop. Your IDE might help you to generate the `equals()` as well.

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
     boolean isEqual = (this == object);
     if(object instanceof Variant){
          Variant variant = (Variant) object;
          isEqual = this.quantity.equals(variant.quantity);
     }else{
         isEqual = false;
     }

     return isEqual;
  }
  ```
- Check if the List contains the object - which will use the `equals()` to check if both are equal.

  ```
  for (Variant variant : variantList) {
     if (variantList.contains(variant)) {
        //do logic if its present
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below guidelines:

1. Your Class `Variant` must `override` the `equals` method, since you define a **duplicate** condition based on **quality** hence in the `equals` method check for quality attribute value i.e.

   ```
   public class Variant {
       private String variant;
       private String quantity;

   public Variant(String variant, String quantity) {
       this.variant = variant;
       this.quantity = quantity;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1;
       result = prime * result
               + ((quantity == null) ? 0 : quantity.hashCode());
       return result;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       Variant other = (Variant) obj;
       if (quantity == null) {
           if (other.quantity != null)
               return false;
       } else if (!quantity.equals(other.quantity))
           return false;
       return true;
   }


   }
   ```
2. Create a method which basically **checking** whether your list contains the duplicate entries(Variant) or not and return **true** and **false** accordingly:

```
private static boolean isListContainsDuplicateEntries(
            ArrayList variantList) {
        final List setToReturn = new ArrayList();
        for (Variant v : variantList) {
            if (!setToReturn.contains(v)) {
                setToReturn.add(v);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

3. Now, test the **functionality**:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
           Variant variant1 = new Variant("1", "100");
           Variant variant2 = new Variant("2", "200");
           Variant variant3 = new Variant("3", "200");
   ```

   ArrayList<Variant> variantList = new ArrayList<>();
       variantList.add(variant1);
       variantList.add(variant2);
       variantList.add(variant3);

       System.out.println(Variant.isListContainsDuplicateEntries(variantList));

> Output: true

Comment: This should work, although I'd use a structure backed up by some form of a hashtable over a list (which cuts worst-case runtime from O(n^2) to O(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()`:

```
if (variantList.contains(**<some other Variant object>**)){ 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override your equals method in your `Variant` and try like this

```
 List<Varient> list =getVariantsList();
        System.out.println("here list size"+list.size());
        Set<Varient> set = new HashSet<Varient>(list);
        System.out.println("here"+set.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a varient Object:

```
  public class Varient {

    private String variant;
    private String quantity;


public String getVariant() {
    return variant;
}

public void setVariant(String variant) {
    this.variant = variant;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Varient)) return false;

    Varient varient = (Varient) o;

    if (!quantity.equals(varient.quantity)) return false;
    if (!variant.equals(varient.variant)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = variant.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + quantity.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

}

Here is your main Program;

```
public class Test {
        public static void main (String [] args){
// getVariantsList() here your list
            List<Varient> list =getVariantsList();
            Set<Varient> set = new LinkedHashSet<Varient>(list);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Variant {

    private String variant;
    private String quantity;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((variant == null) ? 0 : variant.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Variant other = (Variant) obj;
        if (variant == null) {
            if (other.variant != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!variant.equals(other.variant))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getVariant() {
        return variant;
    }

    public void setVariant(String variant) {
        this.variant = variant;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // HashSet<Variant> set = new HashSet<>();


        // LinkedHashSet<Variant> linkedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // stores
        // in input order

        /*
         * You can use treeset to store data in custom order, in this case
         * lexicographically
         */
        TreeSet<Variant> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(new VariantComparator());
    }
}
```